# Find the top right coordinate of a square given its bottom left coordinate

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Given the bottom left coordinates of a square and the side length of the square, how do you find out the top right coordinates of the square?

Example: $(-10,-2)$ is the bottom left coordinates of the square. And the side length of the square is $7$. The top right coordinates is $(-3,5)$. How?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions. Also, in order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Add $7$ to each coordinate, 
$(-10+7,-2+7)=(-3,5)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Similar to the asker, please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your are asking for some kind of general formula. So, here we go, let's assume that $(x_a,y_a)$ is the below left corner of your square and length of side is L, then the formula for co-ordinate of above right corner will be,

$=({x_a}+L,{y_a}+L)$.

Here, we have to assume that the sides of the square is parrallel to x and y axis.

Comment: But if you ignore the assumption you have made, then your formula no longer holds true.In such a case how will you solve it?

Comment: then the present statement of the problem is incomplete, we need extra information about orientation of square

Comment: Okay.Thank you for your instant reply.